# Tomcat session replication through mod_jk, getting expired when one is down

Tags: session, tomcat

I have setup session replication between two tomcats running on different machine using mod_jk, when one tomcat is down, my session is getting expired, and when I refresh its going to next tomcat. But ideally, it shouldn't get expired. Any help will be highly appreciated. Here is my config files.

Server.xml

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="worker1">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->
<!-- Clustering configuration start -->
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" channelSendOptions="8">    

        <!--<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
        expireSessionsOnShutdown="false"        
        notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>-->

        <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">

            <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
            address="228.0.0.4"
            port="45564" frequency="500"
            dropTime="3000"/>           
            <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">                
                <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"/>              
            </Sender>           
            <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver" 
            address="auto" port="4000" autoBind="100"
            selectorTimeout="5000" maxThreads="6"/>                     
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>         
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>   
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.ThroughputInterceptor"/>                      
        </Channel>

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" />       
        <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener" />   


workers.properties

# First we define virtual worker's list
worker.list=jkstatus,LoadBalancer

# Enable virtual workers earlier
worker.jkstatus.type=status
worker.LoadBalancer.type=lb

# Add Tomcat instances as workers, three workers in our case
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.host=localhost
worker.worker1.port=8009

worker.worker2.type=ajp13
worker.worker2.host=10.57.79.232
worker.worker2.port=8019

# Provide workers list to the load balancer
worker.LoadBalancer.balance_workers=worker1,worker2
```

Comment: So, you want sticky-sessions, but with clustering to provide fail-over? What version of Tomcat? Do you have any relevant logs to post? You might want to confirm that your multicast is working and that the sessions are in fact being replicated.

Comment: Yes, we would need sticky sessions, that's working fine, but when one tomcat is down my session getting expired and when we refresh, it shows us login page. Logs doesn't have any information to show. Multicast is working fine, one more thing, one machine is linux and another is windows in the cluster, will that make any difference ?

Comment: Linux/Windows should not matter, though I'm sure the admins *love* that deployment. What is your Tomcat version?

Comment: Yes, ideally it shouldn't matter. Our version is tomcat 7